# Parsing more than one value from XML element

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have a `XML` column in a SQL Server 2012 database table, and one particular element in the XML stores multiple values. The issue I have is that I don't know what the max values of those child elements are. It could be 2, 3 or 10 etc.

I need a way to extract the multiple values in the XML element `SomeFieldName` and return it in one row. I have a simplified example of my issue below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #temptable

CREATE TABLE #temptable ([CustomFieldsXML] xml)

INSERT INTO #temptable ([CustomFieldsXML])
VALUES
('<values>
    <SomeFieldName>
    <item>
      <Key>ph</Key>
      <Value>Philippines</Value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <Key>my</Key>
      <Value>Malaysia</Value>
    </item>
  </SomeFieldName>
</values>' )

SELECT
    c.CustomFieldsXML,
    c.CustomFieldsXML.value('(/values/SomeFieldName/item/Value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'Value1',
    c.CustomFieldsXML.value('(/values/SomeFieldName/item/Value)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'Value2'
FROM 
    #temptable AS c

DROP TABLE #temptable;
```

You can see in my example I know how to statically get the values out one by one into different columns. Is there a way to output these values into one row, without knowing the max number of child elements in the tag "SomeFieldName".

My example only shows two, but I would like to know how to deal with an unknown number of values and concatenate into one row, with one column (so that it returns Philippines, Malaysia).  ....Perhaps using a CROSS APPLY? Or is this better suited using XPATH of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `nodes` method to get one row per `item` node, and then you can get the `value`:

```sql
SELECT tt.CustomFieldsXML,
       SFN.i.value('(Key/text())[1]','nvarchar(2)') AS [Key], --Why use MAX here? Can the string really be more than 4,000 characters long?
       SFN.i.value('(Value/text())[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS [Value] --Don't use single quotes for aliases; it's a bad habit and can have unexpected behaviour
FROM #temptable AS tt
     CROSS APPLY tt.CustomFieldsXML.nodes('/values/SomeFieldName/item')SFN(i);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the additional comments about the datatypes and single quotes, but what you have suggested here still returns two rows of data for me. I don't see how the CROSS APPLY here will return the data into a single row for both values from 'Key'. Plus arent you still specifying only returning the one value, [1], from Key and Value? I want both bits of data from VALUE only. So it should return Philippines and Malaysia in one row, without statically stating the number of rows it needs to parse.

Comment: Don't try to get an unknown number of values into an unknown number of columns, @CJ_2022 . Use rows. A dataset needs to be well defined, so you *can't* have a dynamic number of column without dynamic SQL; that is not a path you should be going to for something like this. If you need to pivot the data, I suggest you do that in the presentation layer afterwards; leave the dataset in a normalised form.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, it is to get that one tag "SomeFieldName" that could have multiple values, but I want to concatenate those values into one new column. So the rows you have transposed will end up as one row as Philippines, Malaysia. Is that possible or easily achievable?

Comment: If you want it in one column, you could aggregate it afterwards. I would suggest you edit your question to show what you *actually* want, as I don't want to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

XQuery is very powerful language. It is very easy to get a comma separated list out of XML in one shot.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, CustomFieldsXML xml);
INSERT INTO @tbl ([CustomFieldsXML])
VALUES
('<values>
    <SomeFieldName>
    <item>
      <Key>ph</Key>
      <Value>Philippines</Value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <Key>my</Key>
      <Value>Malaysia</Value>
    </item>
  </SomeFieldName>
</values>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , REPLACE(c.query('data(item/Value/text())')
        .value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        , SPACE(1), ',') AS countries
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY CustomFieldsXML.nodes('/values/SomeFieldName') AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------------+
| ID |      countries       |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | Philippines,Malaysia |
+----+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Yitzhak. I had already resolved the issue with help from Larnu, but appreciate this additional method you have posted as well.